# Map and replace product prices from one 2d array to another 2d array then sort by updated prices

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, mapping

I'm trying to compare 2 sets of array against same key `product_sku`

Array over API (JSON Response)

```
$array1 = array (
    "products" => array(
        "category" => array(
            array(
                "product_sku" => "1",
                "product_type" => "Type",
                "customer_contact_name" => "Contact Name",
                "customer_telephone" => "0000 000 000",
                "customer_email" => "email@email.com",
                "customer_postcode" => "PostCode",
                "additional_info" => array(
                    "some information" => "some information"
                ),
                "full_price" => "50.00",
                "product_name" => "Product Name",
                "product_id" => "1",
                "customer_rating" => "0"
            ),
            array(
                "product_sku" => "2",
                "product_type" => "Type",
                "customer_contact_name" => "Contact Name",
                "customer_telephone" => "0000 000 000",
                "customer_email" => "email@email.com",
                "customer_postcode" => "PostCode",
                "additional_info" => array(
                    "some information" => "some information"
                ),
                "full_price" => "100.00",
                "product_name" => "Product Name",
                "product_id" => "2",
                "customer_rating" => "0"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Array over local database (mysqli query)

```
$array2 = array (
    array(
        "product_sku" => "1",
        "product_type" => "Type",
        "contact_name" => "Contact Name",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "full_price" => "0.00",
        "product_name" => "Product Name",
        "product_id" => "1",
        "rating" => "0"
    ),
    array(
        "product_sku" => "3",
        "product_type" => "Type",
        "contact_name" => "Contact Name",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "full_price" => "80.00",
        "product_name" => "Product Name",
        "product_id" => "3",
        "rating" => "0"
    )
);
```

Goals are

1. Check `$array2` against `$array1` and Only if `product_sku` match (exist in `$array1`), get the `full_price` from `$array1` and replace `full_price` value in `$array2`
2. if `product_id` in `$array1` doesn't exist in `$array2`, just ignore those products.
3. sort product prices (lower to higher) using `sort` function

What I've tried is, partially worked but not able to sort the products prices (lower to higher) using `sort` function and it shows 0.00 `full_price` value of some products

```
$apiarray = $array1["products"]["category"];

foreach ($array2 as $arr2) {
    foreach ($apiarray as $arr1) {
        if ($arr1['product_sku']==$arr2['product_sku']) {
            echo $arr2['product_sku']; // Product from $array2
            echo number_format($arr1['full_price'],2); // Price from $array1
        } else {
            echo $arr2['product_sku']; // Product from $array2
            echo number_format($arr2['full_price'],2); // Price from $array2
        }
    }
)
```

I need help to figure it our or point me right direction how can I achieve the goals

Comment: _it shows 0.00 full_price value of some products_ Thats because you have not even attempted to amend the price in `$array2` Echoing stuff does not change anything

Comment: I dont see any attempt at sorting anything either. **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was using `sort($array)` before on `$array2` where `full_price` is first element, so it auto sort the prices from lower to higher and was planning to use same approach if I be able to solve above mention problem and I thought comparing `full_price` from both array will be enough to get me the desired result and If I know how to amend the price in `$array2` i wouldn't be asking a question here. Do not write code for me but at least have the courtesy to point in right direction

Comment: Please feel free to ask for help with coding problems, but the idea is you try to write the code and we try to help you fix it. You provided a Specification and very little of your own code to show you had made an attempt at writing the code to satisfy that requirement. So that looks to all like a do it for me question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
//Make a temp associative array. This will make the product_sku as the key
//This is to make it easier to check if product_sku exist
$arrayTemp1 = array_column($array1['products']['category'], null, 'product_sku');

//Loop thru the array2.
//Check if the key exist on temp array. If it does, update the price
foreach( $array2 as &$value ) {
    if ( isset( $arrayTemp1[ $value['product_sku'] ] ) ) 
        $value['full_price'] = $arrayTemp1[ $value['product_sku'] ]['full_price'];
}

//Sort the $array2 using usort
usort( $array2, function($a, $b){
    return $a['full_price'] - $b['full_price'];
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $array2 );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_sku] => 1
            [product_type] => Type
            [contact_name] => Contact Name
            [phone] => 0000 000 000
            [full_price] => 50.00
            [product_name] => Product Name
            [product_id] => 1
            [rating] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_sku] => 3
            [product_type] => Type
            [contact_name] => Contact Name
            [phone] => 0000 000 000
            [full_price] => 80.00
            [product_name] => Product Name
            [product_id] => 3
            [rating] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation, I wasn't aware of the approach `Check if the key exist on temp array` explained in answer, was relying on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php to do the leg work but of course with every hurdle we learn something new, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are not editing `$array2` but only printing in your loops. Your 2nd step isn't necessary, it results from your nested `foreach`.

---

To begin you can get the SKU list as:

```
$sku_list = array_column($array1['products']['category'], 'product_sku');
```

Then to update the prices:

```
// Loop through the 2nd array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i += 1) {
    if (in_array($array2[$i]['product_sku'], $sku_list)) {

        // Get the index of the 1st array item which SKU is matching, and update
        $index = array_search($array2[$i]['product_sku'], $sku_list);
        $array2[$i]['full_price'] = $array1['products']['category'][$index]['full_price'];
    }
}
```

Then to sort using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and PHP7's [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (easy to replace if in lower PHP version):

```
usort($array2, function($a, $b) { return $a['full_price'] <=> $b['full_price']; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This question requires 3 basic tasks if done in PHP. ([Full Demo](https://3v4l.org/r8bcn))

1. Create a lookup array from the `product_sku` values and the `full_price` values.  `array_column()` is the most appropriate function to build the associative array.

   ```
   $skuFullPrices = array_column(
       $array1['products']['category'],
      'full_price',  // column to be values
      'product_sku'  // column to be keys
   );
   ```
2. Map the `full_price` values from the first array to the rows with the corresponding `product_sku` in the second array.

   ```
   $array2 = array_map(
       fn($row) =>
           array_replace(
               $row,
               ['full_price' => $skuFullPrices[$row['product_sku']] ?? $row['full_price']]
           ),
       $array2
   );
   ```

   Or

   ```
   $array2 = array_map(
       function($row) use ($skuFullPrices) {
            $row['full_price'] = $skuFullPrices[$row['product_sku']] ?? $row['full_price'];
            return $row;
       },
       $array2
   );
   ```
3. Sort the updated array from in the second array based on `full_price` values in an ascending direction.

   ```
   usort(
       $array2,
       fn($a, $b) => $a['full_price'] <=> $b['full_price']
   );
   ```

---

That said, modern PHP and modern MYSQL allow this task be wholly and concisely done in SQL.  JSON-encode your API data, pass it as a parameter in a prepared statement as LEFT JOINed derived table, then COALESCE the full_price values and sort by full price.

Code: ([PHPize.online Demo](https://phpize.online/s/oC))

```
$json = json_encode(
    /* $yourarray['products']['category'] */
);

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT prod.product_sku,
       prod.product_type,
       prod.contact_name,
       prod.phone,
       COALESCE(api.full_price, prod.full_price) AS full_price,
       prod.product_name,
       prod.product_id,
       prod.rating
FROM products AS prod
LEFT JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         ?,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
                  product_sku INT PATH '$.product_sku',
                  full_price VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.full_price'
         )
     ) AS api ON prod.product_sku = api.product_sku
ORDER BY full_price
SQL;

var_export(
     $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$json])->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);
```